# qemu on macos: how to release mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, qemu, macos

I see that the window says that I could use `alt + crtl + g`... but that's on a PC keyboard. What would the combination on a mac? I tried with `ctrl + command + g` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Don't use the Command key, it must be the Control key.

Comment: You almost got it. It's `ctrl + option + g`. Feel free to update your answer. I will accept it.

Comment: ctrl+option+g doesn't work for me. command+tab is processed by the host OS allowing me to switch window though - but this is not ideal, since I'm not able to access the QEMU menubar. I'm on macOS BigSur (x86-64)